# App is crashing on emulator when is lauched

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating an `Android` app in which I am using 2 images. If the image being shown is tapped then it fades away and another image appears. But the app is `crashing` at the time of launching.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
boolean imageViewShowing=true;

public void fade(View view)
{
    Log.i("info","Image tapped");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageView imageView2 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    if (imageViewShowing) {
        imageViewShowing = false;

        imageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        imageView2.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
    }else
    {
        imageViewShowing = true;
        imageView2.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        imageView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
    }

}
```

[This image is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqThK.png)

Pardon for silly questions. I have just started.
[screenshot of Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRB9m.png)

[My XML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm83M.png)

[This image creating problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKk9b.png)

Comment: Where is your onCreate method

Comment: Please share the crash log.

Comment: Show you logcat.

Comment: Actually, Logcat in my studio keeps running.

Comment: Learn how to read your logcat

Comment: Post the image of your error log not verbose.

Comment: please take a log of the error from the logcat and post the image

Comment: Add your xml code. The error is in your xml file where you have added the `ImageView`

Comment: Please take a look at MainActivity.java at line 31. There is a Resources$NotFoundException. Check if the resource ID is correct there.

Comment: @SavinSharma I have added the XML code for ImageView

Comment: In which folder you keep your images?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: @MikeM. Okay. I am new to stackoverflow. Thankyou for pointing out

Comment: @Alex res->drawable

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy can you attach the image that you have problem with.

Comment: @Alex I have attached the images

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy i had no issue using this image, everything working.
Try to run on different emulator/device

Comment: I think problem is with studio itself. I was using 3.1.3 version. ThankYou @Alex. That is so kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageView` you have added `app:srcCompact` which is giving you the error. Change it to `android:src` and then try again.

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy do you using vector drawables or regular images(png/jpg)

Comment: I am using a regular image with a .png extension.

Comment: Remove the src part from your xml. Check if still the app is crashing.? If not then add the drawable from your java class.

Comment: @SavinSharma can you please explain why is it happening actually?

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy android:src instead of app:srcCompat should work, android:src is a basic imageview attribute

Comment: I agree with @Alex. Just you basic attribute for your widget.

Comment: @Alex I still have the same problem even after changing accordingly.

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy so if you remove attribute src from xml it is not crashing, but with attribute android:src or app:srcCompat it is crashing?

Comment: @Alex just now I tried with other pics and it is working fine with the original code. Even instead of an image if I use colour then also it works fine. i.e, it's not working with the only earlier image. Why is it so?

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy There are many reasons for that. The picture you used might be corrupted i.e., not a proper png but vector format. Or the picture might be jpg format and changed to png and so on.

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy what is the resolution of this image?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting null pointer exception, because you didn't initialized the ImageView object in the onCreate method. 
You initially using imageview to view some image which have some Image Source, So it must be initialize with the activity not in some method that has to be called on a click/tap. 
You just have to put

```
 ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

here

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageView imageView2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

     imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fade()
        }});        
    }
```

Fade Method should look like

```
public void fade()
{
    Log.i("info","Image tapped")
    if (imageViewShowing) {
        imageViewShowing = false;
        imageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView2.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
        imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else
    {
        imageViewShowing = true;
        imageView2.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Though I think this is most close and clear expaination.

Comment: Can you please show me the line 31 of your onCreate method, also please check whether the image you trying to load isn't too large to load for imageView. Usually ImageView can not load Large images with src xml tag.

Comment: I think the problem is with Image size. As later I tried with a different image and that worked fine. So what size we are allowed to use for an Imageview